# Cant access consul webui docker compose

Tags: docker-compose, consul

Im trying to standup consul dev webui for traning purposes using docker compose.

While consul claims to be running, when I try to visit localhost:8500/ui, the site is unreachable.

My docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:

  cs1:
    image: consul:1.4.2
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    command: "agent -dev -ui"
```

The response from the console is

```
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 | ==> Starting Consul agent...
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 | ==> Consul agent running!
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |            Version: 'v1.4.2'
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |            Node ID: 'dfc6a0ce-3abc-a96d-718b-8b77155a2de6'
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |          Node name: '1fde0528ab0c'
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |         Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '<all>')
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |             Server: true (Bootstrap: false)
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |        Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: 8502, DNS: 8600)
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |       Cluster Addr: 127.0.0.1 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
cs1_1_6d8d914aa536 |            Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false
```

I suspect the site is running on the docker container locahost but port 8500 hasnt been exposed properly.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line `command: "agent -dev -ui"` from your `docker-compose.yml`.

The default command is already running the dev agent, see the Dockerfile here:

https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-consul/blob/9bd2aa7ecf2414b8712e055f2374699148e8941c/0.X/Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

By default, the consul is bind to localhost

```
Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: 8502, DNS: 8600)
```

add [bind](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_bind) to your command usually allowed to any IP (0.0.0.0)

```
agent -dev -ui -bind=0.0.0.0
```