# Connection refused from neo4j docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, neo4j, jar

I have a jar of a spring boot application running in a docker container. I am trying to connect it to a neo4j docker container. I get an error when I hit the url http://localhost:8080/ "Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction". But when I run the jar and neo4j container from two separate machines it connects to the neo4j db. Error only occurs if I run both containers on same host machine. Below is the log:

```
2019-02-25 09:02:52.413 ERROR 6 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ConnectionException: Could not create driver instance] with root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:325) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.6.3.jar!/:1.6.3-b33d284ef6f350edbfe9e8f4539cdcdb0200bd0b]
```

Comment: Have you changed the Neo4j port on your docker container ? Because the default port for neo4j is `7474` for the http protocole

Comment: No the port is same 7474

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind your database to localhost.
Bind to any IP 0.0.0.0
Please read my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54852249/1573395) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804606/1573395). It's help to people have the same problems

Comment: Thank you for your help. Tried changing address from localhost to 0.0.0.0 but issue not resolved.

Comment: You welcome any time. I hope you expose docker port before hitting http://localhost:8080.

Comment: Yes, I am exposing the port 8080 while running the image. Command Iam using to run the jar image: sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 jar_image_name

Comment: Could you please share with us whole ```docker run``` command